# Row index provided is out of range. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#

I trying to move selected items from one gridview to another gridview, when the user has selected items(more than one item). It reads the first row and third row item in gridview and sends it to gridview2.

Gives me the above error in try catch. How do I read each row by row without jumping to read to the third row when user has selected a second row.  I have been working on this for a week now. I am a beginner in C#. Thanks in advance.

```
    // dgSubjectGridView2 is cleared, first Gridview(dgSubjectGridView) is moving selected item from its grid to dgSubjectGridView2

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        dgSubjectGridView2.Rows.Clear();

        try
        {

            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        //Counts the total number of rows in dgSubjectGridView
            for (int i = 0; i < dgSubjectGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                row = dgSubjectGridView.Rows[i];

                Boolean checkstate;

                checkstate = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgSubjectGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if (checkstate == true)
                    {

                        dgSubjectGridView2.Rows.Add(false, item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                        dgSubjectGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //End
        }
    }
```

Comment: This exception is thrown when your index is superior to the size of the collection, this link may help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/245900/Index-was-out-of-range-Datagridview

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are twice looping through the same GridView row collection. Replace your try block with the following code and see if it produce the desired result.

```
try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgSubjectGridView.Rows)
    {
        Boolean checkstate = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value);
        if (checkstate == true)
        {
            dgSubjectGridView2.Rows.Add(false, row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            dgSubjectGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am now able to read each row in gridview

Comment: @Dexter glad to know that it worked. Do, mark it as answer though. Cheers.